# Returning const char* from funciton

Tags: c++, exception, garbage

I have this function, where I'm trying to return a const char*, but when I try to output the returned value, I get garbage value;

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept 
{
    std::stringstream s;
    if(m_id > -1)
        s << m_message << " with id " << m_id << " does not exist";
    else
        s << m_message << " with name " << m_name << " does not exist";
    
    //until now it works fine

    std::string tmp = s.str();
    const char* temp = tmp.c_str();

    return temp; //after I execute this command, the value is deleted.
}
```

when I try to print:

```
catch (std::exception& e) 
{   
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

I get this (different every time..) :

```
▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌╢Pⁿש▌'
```

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: I'd recommend [debugging with address sanitizer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q1b8eEh43).

Comment: @chris , Im working on a project, can I import it there?
And also, I'm working with the visual studio debugger, and I still can't figure out the solution

Comment: The pointer points to `tmp.c_str()` which no longer exists. AKA dangling pointer

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable that will no longer exist. Using that pointer from outside the function is undefined behavior.

Comment: @אמיריפה, It's a compiler option available in all of the three of MSVC, GCC, and Clang.

Comment: `tmp` is a variable of automatic storage duration, so ceases to exist when the function returns.   The data pointed to by `temp`, since it is owned and managed by `tmp`, also ceases to exist when the function returns.    Returning that pointer to the caller gives undefined behaviour (as does dereferencing that pointer to access what it points at).   Anything can happen when behaviour is undefined, and inconsistent output like you are seeing is one possible result.  If you want to return a pointer, you need to ensure the pointee still exists when the pointer is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to the internal `char` data of a local `std::string` object that is destroyed when the function exits, thus the returned pointer is left dangling, pointing at invalid memory. Trying to access the data afterwards is *undefined behavior*.

Normally, you would have two choices to fix that:

- return a `std::string` instead of a `char*` pointer.
- allocate the `char` data dynamically, and then make the caller free it when done using it.

However, in this case, you are overriding the `std::exception::what()` method, so neither of those options are viable.  What you will have to do instead is store your `char` data in a `std::string` member of your derived class, and then you can return a `char*` pointer to its data, eg:

```
private:
    std::string m_what;

myException::myException(...) 
{
    ...
    std::stringstream s;
    if (m_id > -1)
        s << m_message << " with id " << m_id << " does not exist";
    else
        s << m_message << " with name " << m_name << " does not exist";

    m_what = s.str();
}

virtual const char* what() const noexcept 
{
    return m_what.c_str();
}
```

If you derive your exception class from `std::runtime_error` instead of `std::exception` directly, this is already handled for you. `std::runtime_error` takes a string in its constructor, and overrides `what()` to return that string's data.

Comment: thank you very much!
Do you have any idea why ( this->m_what = s.str() ) doesn't compile? it says no operator "=" matches operands (const std::string = std::basic_string<>)

Comment: It is not necessarily a good idea to have a `std::string` member of a class that will be thrown as an exception.  Constructing a `std::string`, which will happen in the process of constructing the object to throw, can *also* throw (with the result being a different exception thrown than expected, such as a `std::bad_alloc` instead of a `myException`), as can copying one (during stack unwinding, the implementation is permitted to copy the exception object - and throwing another exception in that process results in a call to `std::terminate()`).

Comment: @Peter the same can be said for using `std::stringstream` to format the message string while constructing the exception. Though, SSO can help mitigate that risk as long as the string message is kept short. Doing the allocations inside of `what()` is not an option due to `noexcept`. `std::runtime_error` uses some special handling of its internal string memory to avoid this issue.

Comment: the code I have provided is not assigning to a `const string`, so there is a mistake in your code @אמיריפה

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that `tmp` is local to the function `what` and you're returning a pointer to that local's internal array. This is a problem because the local will be destroyed once the function exits. That is, the pointer that you return is a **dangling pointer**. Using that dangling pointer(which you do when you wrote `std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;`) is **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: @RemyLebeau Edited that part out.